# Are there any languages that mark plural before the noun, while everything else comes after?

Tags: linguistic-typology, word-order, grammatical-number, noun-phrases

There's a lot of head-final languages where everything precedes the noun except for the number (Japanese is one example). But are there any that do the reverse? Is there a language where number precedes the noun while all the other elements (such as adjectives and adjectival clauses and whatnot) always come after?

Comment: French. -------

Comment: @GregLee. Broadly speaking: yes. Why don't you elaborate it to an answer?

Answer (score 7):

WALS is a great tool to answer questions like this. With [this combined view of three features](http://wals.info/combinations/87A_89A_33A#2/24.9/153.0) I find Zapotec and Sre as languages with the following features:

```
    Plural prefix / Noun-Adjective / Numeral-Noun
```

Comment: I think the question was about plural markers, not numerals.

Comment: @fdb That's what I thought from the question title, but that's not what the question body asked.